# Pointers to Structures in C programming

Tags: c, struct

I was trying to understand a concept in Structures of C and was confused with the use of pointers with it. The code that I am working on looks like this :

```
struct entry_s {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct entry_s *next;
};

typedef struct entry_s entry_t;

struct hashtable_s {
    int size;
    struct entry_s **table; 
};

typedef struct hashtable_s hashtable_t;

hashtable_t *ht_create( int size ) {
    ............
    ............
}
```

Here I am confused at the last line i.e I dont really understand what it means.

```
 hashtable_t *ht_create( int size )
```

Could somebody please explain that?

Comment: `ht_create()` is a function which takes `size` as argument and returns a pointer of type `hashtable_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hashtable_t *ht_create( int size ) {
```

this is the beginning of a function. It recieveds an integer, which it will call size and at the end of the function it will return a pointer to the hashtable it has created.

This function might be called from main by something like

```
p_hashtable = ht_create(10);
```

where p_hashtable has been created as a pointer to a hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

`hashtable_t *ht_create( int size ) {`  starts a function named *ht_create* that takes a single integer parameter *size* and returns a pointer to a *hashtable_t*.

In general, in C functions that need to return or pass back structures return pointers to the structures.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typedef:

```
typedef struct hashtable_s hashtable_t;
```

So

```
hashtable_t *ht_create( int size )
```

is the same as

```
struct hashtable_s *ht_create( int size )
```

which is a function that takes in an `int` as a parameter and returns a pointer of type `struct hashtable_s*`.

Answer (score 0):

`ht_create` is just a function which, as its name implies, creates a hash table of a given size.

It probably does something like this:

```
hashtable_t *ht_create( int size )
{
    hashtable_t *ht = malloc(sizeof(*ht));           // allocate hashtable_s struct
    ht->size = size;                                 // init size field
    ht->table = calloc(size, sizeof(ht->table[0]));  // allocate/init table itself
    return ht;                                       // return pointer to newly-created hashtable_s
}
```

Comment: Except that the code declares `struct entry_s **table;` which doesn't make any sense. You'll get a pointer-to-pointer pointing at a one dimensional array.

Comment: @Lundin: I think it's meant to be a 1D array (of size `size`) of pointers to `struct entry_s`, but who knows ?

Answer (score 0):

It declares a function with name `ht_create`. That function takes an `int` parameter and returns a `hashtable_t*`.  A `hashtable_t*` is a pointer to a `hashtable_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote the code was probably a bit confused about pointers and arrays in C, since `struct entry_s **table;` doesn't make any sense.

The function returns a pointer to `hashtable_t` which is supposedly an allocated hashtable. In this case the program, if written correctly, allocates `size` number of `struct entry_s` as an array allocated in adjacent memory. And then each entry has a linked list of entries. This is known as "chaining".

Why you would need a `struct entry_s **` I have no idea, and probably not the person who wrote the code either. A single pointer should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the * means that the function returns the **pointer to**, *the address in memory* of the created hashtable.

**EDIT:**
Going a bit deeper, the '*' operator means 'value of', while '&' means 'address of'

In the assembly level, every variable has a cell, or N consequential cells, reserved in memory. So consider the following code:

```
struct st{ 
int a; 
char ch; 
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
    struct st obj; 
    struct st *stobj;
    *stobj = &obj; 
}
```

What this row ***stobj = &obj;** really does is

(the value of) stobj = (the address of) obj

as the pointer is meant to hold not the object itself, but rather objects address in memory